# how to display a Matlab window that contains just simple, multi-line text instructions

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to display a multi-line list of instructions in a window, that is shown when I run my script.

I've tried the code below, but I don't want to have to 'fine tune' the x,y position of each line.  Is there a way to quickly specify and display multiple lines of text to a window, like a figure window?

In VisualBasic, for example, this would be like appending text to a label.

```
f = figure('menu','none','toolbar','none');
uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[0 45 120 20],'String','AAA');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` and `\n` to get multiple lines. The additional `HorizontalAlignment`-property aligns the text horizontally. Then you just need to fine fine-tune the overall position.

```
f = figure('menu','none','toolbar','none');

txt = sprintf('Line 1\nA longer line 2\nLine 3');

uicontrol('Style','text','Position',[30 45 180 40],'String',txt,...
    'HorizontalAlignment','left');
```

*This looks like this:*

[image: pic1]